# How to use REGEX_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to extract a substring from a long string. I tried the following query but doesn't work , it returns me NULL,
I want to extract the first value 12 between the `<cc>` and `</cc>`

```
select regexp_substr('<CC>3</CC><CN>ROSSI</CN><NO>MARIO</NO><IN>VIA DELLE MIMOSE 4</IN>,'<CN>[^</CN>]*') 
"REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
FROM DUAL;
```

I get as a result `<CN>ROSSI` but I want also to eliminate also the  `<CN>` , any suggestion?

Comment: Which following query? Please provide us your code.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a regular expression to parse XML data; use a proper XML parser:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '/root'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(
           '<root>'
           || '<CC>3</CC><CN>ROSSI</CN><NO>MARIO</NO><IN>VIA DELLE MIMOSE 4</IN>'
           || '</root>'
         )
         COLUMNS
           cc NUMBER PATH './CC',
           cn VARCHAR2(20) PATH './CN',
           no VARCHAR2(20) PATH './NO',
           "IN" VARCHAR2(50) PATH './IN'
       ) t
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> CC | CN    | NO    | IN                
> -: | :---- | :---- | :-----------------
>  3 | ROSSI | MARIO | VIA DELLE MIMOSE 4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfd2dea21801969dba19294bfd47ce26)*

Comment: Good one +1, I wonder why people store/treat XML as string. Beats the purpose!

Comment: "use a proper XML parser" +1

Comment: Just - in the name of all that's good in the world! - [DON'T TRY TO PARSE HTML WITH A REGEX!!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/213136)

Answer (score 0):

You may get `ROSSI` using

```
select regexp_substr('<CC>3</CC><CN>ROSSI</CN><NO>MARIO</NO><IN>VIA DELLE MIMOSE 4</IN>','<CN>([^<]*)</CN>', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

See the [online Oracle demo](https://rextester.com/PRJMXX34084).

The `<CN>([^<]*)</CN>` regex matches `<CN>`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `<` and then matches `</CN>`. Only the captured part is returned due to the last argument `1`.

Comment: This won't match anything if the `CN` element contains nested tags such as `<CN><B>ROSSI</B></CN>` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=75d0fdf429e29acce1e43d92287d80db).

Comment: @MT0 The tags OP shows are not nested. Otherwise, no regex in Oracle could help and I would have not shared this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subexpression (a matching group enclosed in parentheses) to grab what you want:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('<CC>3</CC><CN>ROSSI</CN><NO>MARIO</NO><IN>VIA DELLE MIMOSE 4</IN>',
                     '<CN>(.*?)</CN>', 1, 1, NULL, 1) 
  FROM DUAL;
```

Here we're telling `REGEXP_SUBSTR` that we want to match a string which begins with `<CN>`, is followed by a subexpression of any number of any characters `(.*)`, and ends when `</CN>` is found. Because there's only a single subexpression (`(.*?)`) in the regular expression it's sub-expression number 1, which is indicated by the last parameter passed to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` above.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a54a04d8ae7db88ba4da7165cf50faed)

Comment: If there is another `</CN>` tag in the input then this will not work [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=719f4e1b2e3312cac4206313b8a349cb).

Comment: OK - so make the sub-expression non-greedy. Fixed up the answer, and changed the fiddle to show how the original greedy sub-expression wouldn't work as desired if there were multiple `<CN>'`s in the data (which, of course, is not what OP showed, but I'm game :-), and how using a non-greedy sub-expression makes it happy again. Of course, it doesn't capture the second `<CN></CN>` and subsequent pairs, but as we're somewhat far afield of the original question we'll leave the solution to that problem as an exercise for the motivated reader. :-)